# Unit test singleton class method in android using PowerMock

Tags: java, android, mockito, rx-java, powermock

I need to do unit testing of methods of Singleton class which internally uses RxJava Singles, and used PowerMock test framework to mock static class and methods. I tried various method to mock Schedulers.io() and AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() methods but it's not working. I'm getting **java.lang.NullPointerException** error at line                 **.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())** inside **UserApi.verifyUserData()** method.

> Singleton Class UserApi (Class under Test)

```
final public class UserApi {
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;
    private String userID; 
    //private final SchedulerProvider schedulerProvider;

    private UserApi(String userId) {
        super();
        this.userID = userId;
        //this.schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
    }

    public static UserApi getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.sINSTANCE;
    }

    private static final class SingletonHolder {
        private static final UserApi sINSTANCE;

        static {
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            sINSTANCE = new UserApi(uuid);
        }
    }

    // Rest Api call

    public void verifyUserData(byte[] doc, byte[] img) {
        this.compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        String docStr = Base64.encodeToString(doc, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String imgStr = Base64.encodeToString(img, Base64.NO_WRAP);

        final Disposable apiDisposable = IdvManager.getInstance().getUserManager().verifyUserData(docStr, imgStr)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(JsonObject verifyResponse) throws Exception {
                        pollResult();
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable error) throws Exception {
                      // handle error code...
                    }
                });
        this.compositeDisposable.add(apiDisposable);
    }

    private void pollResult() {
        // code here...
    }

}
```

> UserManager Class and Interface

```
public interface UserManager {

    Single<JsonObject> verifyUserData(String docStr, String imgStr);

}

final class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager {

    private final UserService userService;

    UserManagerImpl(final Retrofit retrofit) {
        super();
        this.userService = retrofit.create(UserService.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Single<JsonObject> verifyUserData(String docStr, String imgStr) {
     // Code here...
    }
}
```

> Unit Test

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({IdvManager.class, Base64.class, Schedulers.class, AndroidSchedulers.class, UserApi.class})
public class UserApiTest {

    @Mock
    public UserManager userManager;
    @Mock
    private Handler handler;

    private IdvManager idvManager;
    private Schedulers schedulers;

    private UserApi spyUserApi;
    private TestScheduler testScheduler;
    private String userID;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        handler = new Handler();
        PowerMockito.suppress(constructor(IdvManager.class));
        // mock static
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(IdvManager.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Schedulers.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(AndroidSchedulers.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Base64.class);
        // Create mock for class
        idvManager = PowerMockito.mock(IdvManager.class);
        schedulers = PowerMockito.mock(Schedulers.class);
        PowerMockito.when(IdvManager.getInstance()).thenReturn(IdvManager);
        when(idvManager.getUserManager()).thenReturn(userManager);

        spyUserApi = PowerMockito.spy(UserApi.getInstance());
        // TestSchedulerProvider testSchedulerProvider = new TestSchedulerProvider(testScheduler);

        when(Base64.encodeToString((byte[]) any(), anyInt())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((byte[]) invocation.getArguments()[0]);
            }
        });

        when(schedulers.io()).thenReturn(testScheduler);
        when(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).thenReturn(testScheduler);
        userID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    @After
    public void clearMocks() {
        //Mockito.framework().clearInlineMocks();
    }

    @Test
    public void verifyUserData_callsPollResult_returnsResponse() {
        // Input
        String docStr = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ4AAACeCAYAAADDhbN7AA.....";
        // Output
        JsonObject verifyResponse = new JsonObject();
        verifyResponse.addProperty("status", "Response created");
        doReturn(Single.just(verifyResponse)).when(userManager).verifyUserData(docStr, docStr);
        // spy method call
        spyUserApi.verifyUserData(docFrontArr, docFrontArr);
        testScheduler.triggerActions();
        // assert
        verify(userManager).verifyUserData(docStr, docStr);

    }
}
```

> Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rahul.manager.UserApi.verifyUserData(UserApi.java:60)
    at com.rahul.manager.UserApiTest.verifyUserData_callsPollResult_returnsResponse(UserApiTest.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I'm not sure whether i can test methods of Singleton class by spying on real instance of Singleton class using PowerMock.

Comment: Try adding UserAPI.class in the prepare annotation

Comment: @Sergio i have added it actually did typo error while posting, now corrected.

Comment: Is `UserManager` one of your classes? If what you are saying is correct then `verifyUserData` would return `null`, which either is due to the parameters definend for the mock not matching or because the variable `userManager` is `null`. You might want to remove anything unrelated from your class and the test, then you can post a [mre].

Comment: @second UserManger is interface which is implemented by corresponding class and i have mocked the same, also added the required code in post above. So that is not creating any issue. Actually the nullPointerException error is coming when Schedulers.io() method is invoked through RxJava Single method. I'm not sure whether i can test singleton class method by spying on real instance of UserApi after calling UserApi.getInstance() method.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your code is complex because it's not testable and it's not extensible. It contains hardcoded dependencies everywhere (e.g. user id, handler, several singletons).
If you decide to use another id generation approach or another handler, you won't be able to do this without rewriting whole class.
Instead of hardcoding dependencies, ask for them in constructor (for mandatory dependencies) or setters (for optional ones).
This will make your code extensible and testable. After you do this, you will see your class contains several responsibilities, after moving them into separate classes, you will get much better picture :-)

For example:

```
public UserApi(String userId, Handler handle) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.handler = handler;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @nickolay I have removed the handler and other extra code and update the same in above post. My issue is different which is because of Schedulers.io() passed in RxJava Single's subscribeOn() method. I'm not sure whether i can test singleton class method by spying on real instance of UserApi class after calling UserApi.getInstance() method.

Comment: @RahulKumar the problem with this code, that I see, is there are too much in a single class. Singletons are not bad but invoking them in a hidden way makes testing and extending this class extremely hard. Ideally we should not have "new" keyword used in our methods. UserApi#verifyUserData method needs UserManager. Instead of getting it yourself from a singleton or some static stuff, just ask for it in UserApi constructor. It's a responsibility of UserApi users to pass proper UserManager instance. For details see http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/ Misko taught Googlers to use TDD.

Answer (score 0):

`Schedulers.io()` is a static method, so you need to use `mockStatic` (which you did) and define the related mock accordingly.

I rearranged your `setup` method a bit, to improve the readability and fixed the mistake. You do not need an instance of `Schedulers` (The variable you named `schedulers`).

*Probably a simple typo you made, as you did the right thing for `Base64` and `AndroidSchedulers`.*

```java
@Before
public void setUp() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    handler = new Handler();

    // mock for instance of `IdvManager` 
    PowerMockito.suppress(constructor(IdvManager.class));
    idvManager = PowerMockito.mock(IdvManager.class);
    when(idvManager.getUserManager()).thenReturn(userManager);

    // mock for `IdvManager` class
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(IdvManager.class);
    PowerMockito.when(IdvManager.getInstance()).thenReturn(idvManager);

    // mock for `Schedulers` class
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Schedulers.class);
    when(Schedulers.io()).thenReturn(testScheduler);

    // spy for instance of `UserApi`
    spyUserApi = PowerMockito.spy(UserApi.getInstance());

    // mock for `Base64` class
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Base64.class);
    when(Base64.encodeToString((byte[]) any(), anyInt())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((byte[]) invocation.getArguments()[0]);
        }
    });

    // mock for `AndroidSchedulers` class
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(AndroidSchedulers.class);
    when(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).thenReturn(testScheduler);

    userID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

---

However the `NPE` is missing the part that actually indicates its failing from this, consider adding it if that does not solve your problem.